# select maximum value of id from mysql table and save it as variable

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to extract highest id from table (in this case 9) and return it as variable $maximum, which I can use later as integer?

[image: IMG]

Comment: Yes, user MAX() function of MySQL.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the How to Ask guide for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Posting code as images is bad as it's not serchable, please add your code as formatted text

Comment: Further to @DDS comment, IMO you don't need to enclose a picture of your table... your question is rather simple and self-contained. You may want to add some code showing how you plan to use that variable value ... perhaps that would change the answer so slightly but that is only a plus.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX()` function. Doc can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column.html)

Comment: I tried it that way, but every time I got 500 internal server error

Comment: Please share your php code for executing the query.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM amx_amxadmins");

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following snippet:

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM some_table where id = (select max(id) from some_table)"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id = " . $row["id"];
    }
}
```

Comment: id = Error: SELECT MAX(id) FROM amx_amxadmins

Comment: it outputs the exact id, but also id = 9Error: SELECT * FROM amx_amxadmins where id = (select max(id) from amx_amxadmins) , how can I get rid of that error?

Comment: Can you share your code and the screen shot of the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will must work.

```
$sql =  "SELECT id FROM some_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id = " . $row["id"];
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, but it outputs also this: id = 9Error: SELECT id FROM amx_amxadmins ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: you can get it direct with id as well. if it works then mark it green tick :-)

Comment: if you need it into a variable then use this
$id = 0; 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
    }
} 
echo $id;

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will must work.

```
$sql =  "SELECT id FROM some_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$id = 0; 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
    }
} 

echo $id;
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you.

Comment: @AdamRose Mark this answer green tick as accepted if it resolved your issue. Thanks